# Variable arraylength and template input in C++11

Tags: arrays, templates, pointers, c++11, constants

I've seen tons of questions about this. Some have answers, some don't, but none seem to work for me. I have this program (somebody else wrote it) that I wish to use. However there are two problems in the constructor:

```
template<unsigned N>
class Enumeration {
public:
Enumeration(const array<vector<pair<unsigned char, double>>, N>& pDistribution);
}
```

The problem with this is that I wish to run this class on user defined input. This input decides the value of N. But because of the 1. const requirement on N for arrays, seeing as I need to construct the array that I will use in the constructor and 2. the const requirement N for templates, I am in quite a pickle.

I tried double pointers, using a proxing class or constexpr voids, non seem to work (depending on whether I did it correctly, I'm reletively new in C++).

My last resort is to do something really ugly with a many-cases switch-statement, but I was hoping someone here can help me out. Preferably without using an extension for the compiler.

Comment: You cannot use this code with N determined by user input. It's just not designed for that.

Comment: If this really boils down to: "Can I chose a template argument at runtime?" the answer is "No". If you want ways to extend and improve the `Enumeration` class to handle both, it is a different story.

Comment: I would like to recreate the Enumeration class, but it was designed by someone else for optimal speed and protected against overwriting of relevant data. Also, the code works recursively and I think templates like this are very good for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you have shown does not support `N` being determined at run-time.  It is intended for a different purpose, for when `N` can be determined at compile time.

Trying to allow `N` be determined at run-time in the above case is almost certainly a bad idea.

Instead, writing a variant of your type such that the outermost container is not an `array` but rather a `vector` would be the general approach required to make the size of the outermost container be determined at run time.

This will involve rewriting most of the class.

```
class Enumeration_Runtime {
public:
  Enumeration_Runtime(const std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned char, double>>>& pDistribution);
};
```

the `const&`ness of the parameter might be best turned into a pass-by-value, but I am unsure.

There is no easy route here, because the person who wrote `Enumeration<N>` wrote it to not allow `N` to vary at run time.